# delay the showing of a ajax loading gif using jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to put a delay on the showing of a ajax-loader gif. When I click a button the loader gif shows and hides even if the time taken is a few hundred milli-seconds, this gives the browser a kind of flicker. What I want is to say only show the gif if it takes more than say 1000 milli-seconds to complete the ajax request.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#loader').hide();
         $('#btnGetPeople').click(function() {
            $('#loader').show();
             $.getJSON("/User/GetName/10",
                null,
                function(data) { showPerson(data); });
         });
     });

     function showPerson(data) {
         alert(data);
         $('#loader').hide();
     }
</script>
```

My loader div contains....

```
<div id="loader"><img alt="" src="/content/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
```

What is the best technique to achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you can see I added a timeout which delay showing for 300ms. If ajax is faster the timeout is cancelled before the loader gets really shown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var showLoader;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#btnGetPeople').click(function() {
            // only show loader if ajax request lasts longer then 300 ms
            showLoader = setTimeout("$('#loader').show()", 300);
            $.getJSON("/User/GetName/10",
                null,
                function(data) { showPerson(data); });
        });
    });

    function showPerson(data) {
        clearTimeout(showLoader);
        alert(data);
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: LOL... thats what I get for being unconventional. Good answer @jitter

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fun way to do it. Replace `$loader.show()` with this:

```
$("#loader").data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function(){ $("#loader").show()}, 1000));
```

And your hide command with this:

```
window.clearTimeout($("#loader").hide().data('timeout'));
```

Comment: @dcneiner, quick q - what is 'timeout'?

Comment: Just a custom `data` attribute to keep the `int` returned from `setTimeout` associated with our DOM object. It is either this or declare another variable like @jitter. I just wanted to show a contained way of doing it with jQuery.

Comment: @RageZ `clearTimeout` only works when passed the same `integer` that was returned from the `setTimeout` function. Since I am storing the `integer` in a custom `data` attribute, it would work fine.

Comment: Doh! Forgot the timeout length... updating my answer :)

Comment: Thanks man :) At the least you will think of possibly using the `data` feature in the future. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Doug, great idea using data!  +1 for sure.  I like not having a global timerid variable.  Thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this.

```
var loadingTimer;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loader").ajaxStart(function () {
        loadingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#loader").show();
        }, 200);
    });

    $("#loader").ajaxStop(function () {
        clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
        $(this).hide();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share something I did for this. I had a situation where I needed to do more than just show or hide the one element.  So I used bind to create custom events for the loader:

```
$("#loader").bind("delayshow", function (event, timeout) {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
        // show the loader
        $self.show();
        /* 
            implement additional code here as needed
        */
    }, timeout));
}).bind("delayhide", function (event) {
    // close and clear timeout
    var $self = $(this);
    clearTimeout($self.hide().data('timeout')); 
    /*
        implement additional code here as needed 
    */
});

// show it with a 500 millisecond delay
$("#loader").trigger('delayshow', 500);

// hide it
$("#loader").trigger('delayhide');
```