# mvc3 Ajax.ActionLink and delaying LoadingElementId from showing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a progress div which absolute positions across the top of the web page.

When I click on a Ajax.ActionLink, sometimes I see it flicker at the top when the request/response is just short of instant.

How can I add a delay so that the progress banner does not show for 500ms?

thank you

**Here is the working code**

```
var showProgress = false;
function AjaxBegin()
{
    showProgress = true;
    setTimeout("if (showProgress) { $('#progress').show(); }", 800);

}
function AjaxComplete()
{
    showProgress = false;
    $("#progress").hide();
}
function AjaxFailure(ajaxContext)
{
    var response = ajaxContext.responseText;
    alert("Error Code [" + ajaxContext.ErrorCode + "] " + response);
}
```

AjaxOptions

```
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;
OnFailure = "AjaxFailure";
OnBegin = "AjaxBegin";
OnComplete = "AjaxComplete";
HttpMethod = "GET";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to handle this yourself.

Rather than specifying a `AjaxOptions.LoadingElementId` you can handle the showing/hiding of your loading element by specifying functions for the `OnBegin` (show it) and `OnComplete` (hide it) events.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460351.aspx for more details on `AjaxOptions`.

There are a few ways of creating the delay - see [How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)

And here's an example that does it with jQuery - [delay the showing of a ajax loading gif using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851569/delay-the-showing-of-a-ajax-loading-gif-using-jquery)